# Java generics + static factory methods = [panic]

Tags: java, generics, static-methods, type-systems

I thought, I would understand Java generics by now. But now I'm helpless again.

I have a generic class where a c-tor constructs correctly-typed instance, while a static factory method produces a type mismatch.

Please look at the following code:

```
public class _GenericFactoryMethods {

  public final static class DemoClass<T1, T2> {
    private final T1 _1;
    private final T2 _2;

    // static factory method
    public static <T1, T2> DemoClass<T1, T2> create(T1 _1, T2 _2) {
      return new DemoClass<T1, T2>(_1, _2);
    }

    // usual c-tor
    public DemoClass(T1 _1, T2 _2) {
      this._1 = _1;
      this._2 = _2;
    }

    public T1 get1() { return _1; }

    public T2 get2() { return _2; }
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    String str = "test";

    Class<? extends CharSequence> _1 = str.getClass();
    CharSequence _2 = str;

    // works
    DemoClass<Class<? extends CharSequence>, CharSequence> dc1 =
        new DemoClass<Class<? extends CharSequence>, CharSequence>(_1, _2);

    // compile error
    DemoClass<Class<? extends CharSequence>, CharSequence> dc2 =
        DemoClass.create(_1, _2);
  }

}
```

The error is:

```
Uncompilable source code - incompatible types
required: _GenericFactoryMethods.DemoClass<java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.CharSequence>,java.lang.CharSequence>
found:    _GenericFactoryMethods.DemoClass<java.lang.Class<capture#794 of ? extends java.lang.CharSequence>,java.lang.CharSequence>
```

Please help to understand and to solve this.
*(I really need static factory methods for some of such classes).*

**EDIT**
Can someone also **explain why** explicit type parameters must be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
DemoClass.<Type1, Type2>create(_1, _2);
```

As I remember from Josh Bloch's presentation of his Effective Java 2nd Edition: "God kills a kitten every time you specify an explicit type parameter". Try to avoid constructions like this.

Comment: Thank you. Well, to write the usual constructor is even longer ;) And for my special case (**not** the example) I really need static factory methods.

Comment: Sigh, there's no chance to beat answers mentioning kittens. Chapeau! ;)

Comment: @sfussenegger: yeah, it's kinda cheating, everyone loves kittens )))

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to explicitly set the generic type:

```
dc2 = DemoClass.<Class<? extends CharSequence>, CharSequence>create(_1, _2);
```